# Angular, Socket.io : Emit an array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

With Angular how can I subscribe to an array of objects like this one:

```
[
    'abc/user2': { room: 'abc/user2', user: 'user2' },
    'abc/admin': { room: 'abc/admin', user: 'admin' }
]
```

Currently this doesn't work :

```
this.socketService.onRoom().subscribe(rooms => {
    this.rooms = rooms;
});
```

With `socketService`:

```
public onRoom() {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
        this.socket.on('room', (data: any) => observer.next(data));
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Mybad, it seems that problem comes from the server (NodeJS/express/socket.io) :

`chat-server.ts`:

```
public rooms: Array<{room: string, user:string}> = [];

(...)
this.rooms[room] = {room: room, user: socket.user};
this.io.emit('room', this.rooms)
console.log('[server]rooms :', this.rooms)
```

Server side, console.log print :

```
[
    'abc/user2': { room: 'abc/user2', user: 'user2' },
    'abc/admin': { room: 'abc/admin', user: 'admin' }
]
```

But clientside in `socketService`, if i do a console.log(data) here :

```
public onRoom() {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
        this.socket.on('room', (data: any) => {
            console.log(data)
            observer.next(data)
        });
    });
}
```

It return :

```
[]
```

But if I emit serverside:

```
this.io.emit('room', Object.keys(this.rooms))
```

Clientside it return:

```
['abc/user2', 'abc/admin']
```

It's look like i can't emit an array of object from socket.io ?

Comment: show us onRoom() method in service.

Comment: @VinkoVorih edited; subscribe work with a simple array of string, but i cant manage to make it work with an array of object

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You have to turn it into an observable of some kind..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    private readonly data = [
        {
            'abc/user2': { room: 'abc/user2', user: 'user2' }
        },
        {
            'abc/admin': { room: 'abc/admin', user: 'admin' }
        }
    ];
    private data$;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data$ = new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next(this.data);
            observer.complete();
        });
    this.data$.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Though there are many other ways (and probably better ways) to do it. Just an example for you since I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You should create observable which you want to return outside of `socket.on` method.

```
public onRoom(): Observable<any> {
    BehaviorSubject<any> toReturn = new BehaviorSubject();
    this.socket.on('room', (data: any) => toReturn.next(data));
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private myArray = [
    'abc/user2': { room: 'abc/user2', user: 'user2' },
    'abc/admin': { room: 'abc/admin', user: 'admin' }
];
private myObservable= Observable.of(this.myArray);
```

You can subscribe to `myObservable` then.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to resolve this problem by not emitting an array of object, but just an object

`chat-server.ts`

```
//public rooms: Array<{room: string, user:string}> = [];
public rooms: any = {};
```

And client side, i convert my object to an array, so that i can iterate throw it in template.

`chat-list.component.ts`

```
this.socketService.onRoom().subscribe(rooms => {
    this.rooms = rooms;
    this.roomsArr = Object.entries(this.rooms);

});
```

Still, I don't understand why i couldn't manage to emit an array of object from socket.io